# Where can I get the FAA data that defines airspace, including MOAs etc.?

Tags: faa, airspace, aeronautical-charts

I was looking at http://www.gelib.com/aeronautical-charts-united-states.htm, where you can download shape files for Google Earth that show US airspaces.  I'm writing some software that has a similar need and need to find a source for this data.  I'm looking for data that defines the extents of airspaces including MOAs, restricted areas, etc.

I have been pouring through the FAA's website with no luck.  The link I referenced above says its source was the National Aeronautical Charting Office (NACO), which I'm having very little luck finding as well.  I think it may have been renamed, thus the poor results.  I also called the FAA and can't seem to find anyone there that knows where to transfer me.

So, does anyone here have any helpful pointers on finding said information?  I want to pull it directly from the source to make sure it is always up-to-date and accurate.

Comment: I hope you are making an open-source data card that would free people from the grip of Jepp updates.

Comment: can you actually download shape files from the gelib.com URL you gave?  I've tried, and don't see anything in GoogleEarth.

Comment: No.  I was able to download some shape files from the link 2NinerRomeo provided in his answer below but they appear to be 2 dimensional shape files.  I'm still looking into that because I don't have much experience working with shape files... maybe they are 3d and I just haven't found the "magic button" in the viewer yet.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it works.... but I'm looking at some of the data from the other sources, and I'm going to try to change it into GoogleEarth KML files.  If I'm successful, I'll followup here.

Comment: Excellent, I'm more interested in the data you use to produce the KMLs than the KMLs themselves so any insight you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: @mins: Sure enough.  I've deleted the comment.

Comment: search for 3D Google Earth Airspace Lloyd Bailey

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the [National Flight Data Center](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/WebHome).  The data appears to be contained in [NASR](https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56+Day+NASR+Subscription). I mentioned in my comment that there may be no official source for spatial data, but I think this may include what you are looking for.

These are derived products. The cannonical definitions are the legal descriptions found in FAA Orders with the prefix 7400. At the time of this writing, [JO 7400.11 (current version E)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1038054) covered airspace classes A,B,C,D and E as well as reporting points. The [JO 7400.10 (current version C)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1039057) covered special use airspaces. Both publications can be found at the [FAA's Website](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/).

Comment: Found some good stuff here, thanks.  My initial opinion is that the airspace files won't suit my needs but there was a lot of other good information there that I needed as well.  Appreciate the link.

Comment: Are the 2D shapefiles the canonical master definitions or derived products? For Class C airspace, for example, does the FAA maintain exact definitions of a cylinder with a given center, radius, and altitude within one or more radarcs having a certain center, inner and outer radii, start and stop radials, etc.?

Comment: I would call these derived products.  The cannonical definitions would be the legal descriptions found in FAA Orders with the prefix 7400. At the time of this comment, order 7400.9Z covered Classes A,B,C,D,E as well as reporting points.  7400.8X covered special use airspaces.,  Both can be found here: http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/#orders  7400.9Z superseded 7400.9Y.  These are published yearly.  I'm not sure what will come after .9Z.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for Aeronautical Navigation Products ([AeroNav Products](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/)) (formerly NACO).

They have a number of digital products, which should have the data that you are looking for.

If not, their [contact information](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/) is:

> Customer Service:  (800) 626-3677
>   9-AMC-Aerochart@faa.gov
>
> Abigail "Abby" Smith, Director
>   FAA, AeroNav Products AJV-3
>   1305 East-West Hwy
>   Silver Spring, MD 20910
>   (301) 427-5000

Comment: Thanks, I have left a message with them and will post a comment here if I get any good information from them.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [openAIP](http://www.openaip.net). It contains nearly up-to-date airspace and airport information besides other aviation topics. Airspace data is available for download as .aip file. This is actually a very simple XML file that can easily be used in any application.

Comment: OpenAIP is a pretty cool project, but they describe it as a "crowd-sourced aeronautical information platform that allows registered users to add, edit and download aeronautical data" -- that strikes me as having a big red `NOT FOR NAVIGATION - USE OFFICIAL CHARTS FOR FLIGHT` stamp on it :-)

Comment: Or take a look at [Open Flightmaps](https://www.openflightmaps.org), map and raw data as OFMX (a slight variation of AIXM 4.5) as well as a few other formats available.

Answer (score 1):

The current information can be downloaded at:

https://nfdc.faa.gov/xwiki/bin/view/NFDC/56+Day+NASR+Subscription

This includes the digital vector copies of the sectionals and shape files for the airspaces.

Answer (score 1):

FAA's [Coded Instrument Flight Procedures](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/cifp/).

> Data elements included are: Airports and Heliports, Runways, VHF, NDB and ILS Navigation Aids, Waypoints (Terminal and Enroute), Airways, Off Route Obstruction Clearance Altitude (OROCA) records, Departure Procedures (DPs), Standard Terminal Arrival Procedures (STARs), Special Use Airspace (SUAs) and Class B, C, and D Airspace. Also included are GPS, RNAV (GPS), RNAV (RNP), GPS Overlay, ILS, LOC, LDA and SDF Standard Instrument Approach Procedures (SIAPs) with their associated Minimum Safe Altitude (MSA) data.

SUAs most likely includes MOAs.

It's encoded in ARINC 424. The specification is not free but can be found using a search engine.