# What is NASR, The FAA's System for Managing Aeronautical Information?

Tags: faa

I've googled [this question](https://ascelibrary.org/doi/10.1061/40632%28245%2942), and know:

> The National Airspace System Resource (NASR) System provides the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) with the means for storing and maintaining a reference database with descriptive details of the National Airspace System's (NAS's) infrastructure and the operational status of all components

But what I'm asking is, what does that mean? Is this where companies like [AirNav](http://airnav.com/), [Jeppesen](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/), and [foreflight](https://foreflight.com/) get their data? When I update my foreflight database, is it downloading new charts and nav data from NASR, or am I misunderstanding the above quote?

Also, related, when Jeppesen makes their own charts, updates them, etc. are they getting their data from NASR, or somewhere else?

Comment: For the related question you have, see: [How does Jeppesen create its US charts?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34238/14897)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From digging around for a while, I was able to find out that procedures and plates for all airports in the NAS can be found in [this large XML file](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2004/xml_data/d-TPP_Metafile.xml). I haven't been able to find out why approach plates are in a separate XML file, and not in the NASR data, but if anyone is able to give a comprehensive answer to the above question, I'm happy to award a 100 point bounty.

Answer (score 2):

NASR contains the current information upon which Air Traffic Control and other FAA activities depend. NASR supports the management of NAS data used by the FAA, chart producers (including Jeppesen), military and other Government entities to produce a variety of aeronautical publications. Downloads from Foreflight use this data, but may be reformatted to suit the application and would not come directly from any NASR database.

In addition, NASR data is accessed by commercial air carriers, flight planners, and flight systems developers as required by FAA regulation to support the safety-of-flight mission.

The data is available on a 28 day subscription basis. Legacy flat files show the data content, though other forms are available. Definitions for each table are [here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription_2020-03-26/). The tables are:

- Airports and Other Landing Facilities (APT)
- ARTCC Boundary Descriptions (ARB)
- ARTCC Facilities (AFF)
- ASOS/AWOS(AWOS)
- ATC Tower and Satellite Airport Communications (TWR)
- ATS Non-Regulatory Airways (ATS)
- Coded Departure Routes (CDRs) (CDR)
- Country Codes
- Enroute National Fix Program
- Significant Points (NATFIX)
- Fix/Reporting Point/Waypoint (FIX)
- Flight Service Station Communications Facilities (COM)
- Flight Service Stations (FSS)
- High Altitude Redesign (HAR)
- Significant Points (HARFIX)
- Holding Patterns (HPF)
- Instrument Landing Systems (ILS/MLS) (ILS)
- Location Identifiers (LID)
- Miscellaneous Activity Area (MAA)
- Military Training Routes (MTR)
- Navigation Aids (NAV)
- Parachute Jump Area (PJA)
- Preferred Route / Tower Enroute Control (TEC) Routes (PFR)
- Regulatory Airways (AWY)
- Standard Terminal Arrival / Standard Instrument Departure (Complete Set) (STARDP)
- State Codes
- Standard Terminal Arrival / Standard Instrument Departures (AFSS Subset) (SSD)
- Weather Reporting Locations (WXL)