# Where can I find coordinates for Special Use Airspace (e.g. restricted areas) in the USA?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, special-use-airspace

I am looking for exact specifications for a few prohibited and restricted areas near me so I can plot these areas in other mapping software.
I can use sectional charts to estimate, but I am curious if there is some kind of listing that contains coordinates that define these SUAs.

Answer (score 2):

As Pondlife says, [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1248/54557) tells you where to look: All special-use airspace is defined in [JO 7400.10](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1039057). Version C is current as of February 16 2021.